# How to create multiple sub-level menu in joomla 3.0 Administrator

Tags: joomla, joomla3.0

I am developing custom component in Joomla 3.0. I want to add 3 level sub menu in back-end component menu item. Current Joomla shows menu as in below the screen.[image]

---

And I want to add 3 level menu as shows in below screen.

[image]

Can you please help me?
I have added manual Database Entry into Menu table with appropriate parent id but still it does not show in menu list.

Answer (score 2):

I think its not work with 3rd level,

The requirement is important then try to modify the `mod_menu` module .

You can find the module at `administrator\modules\mod_menu`.

I'm also tried not work with DB entry only :(